# invalid_resource AADSTS500011

Tags: azure, azureportal

My MS Teams App was working without any problems for 6 months when suddenly the app had a white screen and printing the following error on the console:

AUTHMSAL: Event: adal:tokenRenewFailure, code: invalid_resource|AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://... was not found in the tenant named . This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
Trace ID: 
Correlation ID: 
Timestamp: 2021-03-01 15:38:07Z, resource: https://..., action: resourceDisabled

Some time ago, my billing account was deleted accidentally but was recovered. I have another app to Excell Addin in the same Tenant ID and it is working.

Any help?

Comment: Follow the error prompt to find out if your resource has been deleted. If resources exist, it is recommended to raise a support ticket on portal.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for reaching out us. We are the developer support team for Microsoft teams focused on helping developers resolve their issues. For issues related to teams product, please reach out to the [product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.